# Homeworkout alternative to deadlifts

Tags: workout-routines, muscle-gain, deadlifts

What are some home workout alternatives to deadlifts? I don't have any gym equipment other than a resistance band.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no single alternative to the deadlift, because the whole point of the deadlift is that it does so many things so dramatically.

It can be loaded more than nearly any other exercise. If this is what you're after, then a **heavy** barbell squat is close. In a home gym, you might be out of luck. Maybe try building an isometric pulling platform.

It works the hamstrings, glutes, lower back, middle back, upper back, and grip. If one of those is what you want, you need to find an exercise that replicates that part of the deadlift. For instance the grip can be targetd with pull-ups or farmer's walks, and the upper back with dumbbell rows.

It's a hinge motion. Home gym hinge exercises include the Jefferson curl, dumbbell/kettlebell swing, and to a much lesser extent "deadlifts" (really a pseudo-deadlift or deadlift-like movement) with an exercise band.

But it's important to remember that few of the best exercises can be simply replaced with another. The greats are great because they're uniquely powerful.

Comment: If you have the barbell for the squat, aren't you already set for deadlift?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- In OP's case maybe, but in general no. Some injuries preclude one but not the other.

Comment: Ah, fair enough, I was only considering equipment.

Comment: I like the isometric idea, though I'm now picturing someone trying to lift the end of a couch with his entire family sitting on it (plus dog)

Comment: @DarkHippo :) I was thinking of http://rosstraining.com/blog/2009/02/homemade-isometric-tool/

Comment: @DaveLiepmann That is very cool, thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 3):

Nordic curls.

Hold your feet under a bed while standing in your knees and use your body as a lever going up and down.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @DaveLiepmann; the deadlift is irreplaceable. Yet, the motion of a
one-legged deadlift with a resistance band might help you mimic the deadlift strength. It is certainly better than nothing.

https://www.google.com/search?q=one+legged+deadlift+band&oq=one+legged+deadlift+band&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.7167j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8